# imap: "Unable to create selectable TCP socket" when sending email from a C++ program

Tags: c++, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to send an email from a C++ program using imap library. I have a Google Apps and a  Gmail account to which I am sending the email.

Whenever the program fails to send an email I am logging the errors to a file.

I set my program to run in loop to send the emails. Sometimes, I don't get the emails and when I checked the log file I found out these errors being logged every time sending the email fails.

Here is the part of the log file:

```
[2012-04-23 11:04:34]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (2753 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:04:34]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (2753 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:05:36]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1692 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:05:36]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1692 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:07:52]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1605 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:07:52]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1605 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:02]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1566 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:02]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1566 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:09]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1067 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:09]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1067 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:19]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1648 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:19]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1648 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:20]   ErrCode:1 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1130 >= 1024)
[2012-04-23 11:08:20]   ErrCode:2 ErrMsg:Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1130 >= 1024)
```

Is it related to imap server port? If so, which port should it be set to? 993 always??
How to troubleshoot this error?

**Here are my setting:**

```
Name: Ashwin
my email: blahblah@wyswtf.com
reply-to-email: blahblah@wyswtf.com
```

**SMTP server information:**

```
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Encryption: SSL
Port: 465
```

The program runs as root user and the library that I am using is from http://panda.com/imap/

Comment: You don't provide enough information, but it sounds like you are asking it to create a server socket instead of a client socket.

Comment: What more information is needed? I am editing the question to post my connection details. In a minute please.. :-) 
My test connection works fine. but when running in loop it causes this problem. What do you mean saying "you are asking it to create a server socket instead of a client socket"??

Comment: Which library, what calls you make to it, do you provide a socket or let it allocate one?  But "server socket" is specifically:  servers generally use ports 0-1023, and on Unixlike systems only processes with `root` permissions can allocate such ports, non-`root` processes will quietly be given other ports — hence the `1130 >= 1024` type messages.

Comment: @geekosaur : here is the library that I am using http://panda.com/imap/

Comment: What platform is this server running on? Update: Never mind, the code is not available so there's no point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library uses some ancient I/O multiplexing code and as a result it can only handle 1,024 connections at a time. Either use a different library or rate-limit your requests to the library.

**Update**: I was going to research this for you and, if necessary, fix the code to work around this or figure out changes to how you build the code. But it seems the library is not publicly available. Sorry, we can't fix closed source code for you.

Comment: Fixed now. The solutions was to change select to poll. ;-) +1 for your post.